# MATLAB: How do I resize (connected) components in a 3D binary image sequence without changing the dimensions of the sequence?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, 3d, volume

I'd like to resize the components contained in a 3D binary image sequence without changing any of the dimensions of the sequence itself.

I'm not sure if I need to do it on a component-by-component basis, if yes, then how do I create a transform such that the resized components are re-positioned 'correctly' in the image sequence? By 'correctly', I mean with the same centre of mass as the original unprocessed components.

(If that last paragraph doesn't make sense then please ignore)

A 2D example: suppose I wanted to enlarge by 10% the white blobs in the following [295x445] image

[image]

How would you do this without making the image itself larger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the [imdilate](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html) function to dilate the regions of interest. The examples in the webpage show how to use this function.